# Google Adsense in android Studio

Tags: adsense

[image: Hello, it seems that I am getting in error while trying to implement google banners ads to my project. It is a restricted access issues. The error message is: 'AdRequest(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder)' has protected access in 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest']

I have tried to used a different coding strategy using the adRequestManager adRequest = new adRequestManager but all in vain. I would like to get some helps to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)